# Ruby on Rails - Rails Admin and Money Gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-admin

Alright so I am trying to use the following code in my payment.rb model to use the Money gem to convert money values to cents for easy storage. The problem is that I cannot figure out how to tell Rails Admin to use this for these fields. I have not found much on how Rails Admin deals with money exactly, in fact I have not been able to find one reference on handling money in Rails Admin.
There has to be a way to do this, if anyone could point me the in the right direction that would be great. Oh I am running

```
  composed_of :fee,
              :class_name => 'Money',
              :mapping => %w(price, cents),
              :converter => Proc.new { |value| Money.new(value) }

  composed_of :other_fee,
              :class_name => 'Money',
              :mapping => %w(price, cents),
              :converter => Proc.new { |value| Money.new(value) }

  composed_of :total,
              :class_name => 'Money',
              :mapping => %w(price, cents),
              :converter => Proc.new { |value| Money.new(value) }

  composed_of :payment_amount,
              :class_name => 'Money',
              :mapping => %w(price, cents),
              :converter => Proc.new { |value| Money.new(value) }
```

Comment: What is your question? Why are you using `composed_of`?
 Have you read [the money gem README?](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails#usage)